# Error Proguard Unsupported class version number

Tags: android, intellij-idea, proguard

I get always this erroe when I try to obfuscate an App with proguard

```
Error:ProGuard: [MyApp] java.io.IOException: Can't read [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\rt.jar] (Can't process class [com/oracle/net/Sdp$1.class] (Unsupported class version number [52.0] (maximum 51.0, Java 1.7)))
```

I have already updated Proguard and checked the project-config file but always the same Error. I'm using the latest version of Intellij IDEA

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Seems that Proguard doesn't support Java 8 actually. You have to use JDK version 7.

EDIT-1

I have recompiled Proguard to support JDK 8 classes, doesn't support Java 8 new features but if your code doesn't use Java 8 new syntax(e.g. Lambda Expression) should works without problems. Tested with some android projects.

To use replace the file proguard.jar in

```
android-sdk\tools\proguard\
```

with the content of [THIS ARCHIVE](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32771602/Proguard-JDK1.8-tolerant.7z)

EDIT-2

Recently has been released the official Proguard 5 that should address the issue. You can download this from [HERE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/files/proguard/)

Comment: I just tried this and got `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value is not a reference value [proguard.evaluation.value.InstructionOffsetValue]`.

Comment: @WonderCsabo
Have you replaced the proguard.jar in `android-sdk\tools\proguard\lib`? I'm using this from a month without any problems. NOTE I'm assuming that the Proguard version were you replace this file is the stable 4.11 downloaded from source-forge
http://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/files/proguard/ and you are using official Oracle Java JDK 1.8

Comment: I have just added the whole proguard folder to avoid version mismatch

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am using the ProGuard version packaged with the Android SDK, it's 4.7. I'll update to the 4.11 version and try your lib again.

Comment: Unfortunately i still got the same error. [This](https://gist.github.com/WonderCsabo/11249889) is the trace. I am on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Damn... The unmodified ProGuard 4.11 also reproduce my issue... [This](http://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/505/?limit=25) is a known ProGuard bug which will be fixed.

Comment: Ah ok. I have only added the ability to tolerate the new JDK if the code doesn't use the new Java 8 syntax, all others issues present in the 4.11 are the same.

Comment: hello, how can I install the proguard 5.2.1?

Answer (score 10):

ProGuard 5.0 (released in August 2014) supports Java 8.

Answer (score 2):

ProGuard has not been updated yet to support Java 8.

An [issue has already been raised against ProGuard](http://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/feature-requests/138/).

Eric Lafortune (ProGuard developer) noted back in October 2013

> I'm very busy at the moment, so realistically I won't be able to complete this in the short term, sorry. I'm keeping an eye on the developments though.

He also said

> ProGuard probably works on class files that only use older features if you change or disable ClassUtil#checkVersionNumbers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a successor of pyx4me ProGuard Maven plugin on github with support to ProGuard 5.2, hence Java 8 support:

https://github.com/wvengen/proguard-maven-plugin

http://wvengen.github.io/proguard-maven-plugin/

Cheers,
Ekho