# How to solve : "Unsupported class version number[52.0] maximum 51.0, Java1.7"?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Can't read

> [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v7.0\mono.android.jar]
>   (Can't process class [android/app/ActivityTracker.class] (Unsupported
>   class version number [52.0] (maximum 51.0, Java 1.7)))

how to solve this issue..??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 in Visual Studio + Xamarin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39879486/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0-in-visual-studio-xamarin)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error Proguard Unsupported class version number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670059/error-proguard-unsupported-class-version-number)

Answer (score 3):

Had this error too. Which JDK Version do you have installed? I had no problems after upgrading it to version 1.8

Alright, if somebody else is reading this with the same problem, upgrading ProGuard seems to fix this problem too. Just try that! :)

Comment: I am using jdk1.7.0_55

Comment: Just try what I suggested, it worked for me. Install JDK version 1.8 and set  in Visual Studio / Xamarin studio

Comment: The latest version of Android build tools require you to install JDK 1.8

Comment: ERROR-Can't read [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v7.0\mono.android.jar] (Can't process class [android/app/ActivityTracker.class] (Unsupported class version number [52.0] (maximum 51.0, Java 1.7)))

Comment: Did you also added the new jdk in visual studio (Tools -> Options -> Xamarin)? And try to clean + rebuild project

Comment: Yeah I know. But just installing isn't enough. Did you added it in Visual Studio? Did you tried my steps I suggested in my last comment? Please provide more information and complete sentences if you want more help.

Comment: every time clean and rebulid the project

Comment: i am also add  jdk 1.8 in visual studio

Comment: Thank u for ur responce..Actually the problem is ProGuard version. it does n't support jdk 1.8 after installing the latest version ProGuard 5.3 it's working..