# Proguard - Can't read StackUtilsImpl.class

Tags: java, netbeans, proguard

I'm having an error while compiling proguard.
**I'm using flatlaf-1.6.4.jar for GUI Java Aplication**

```
Can't process class [META-INF/versions/9/com/formdev/flatlaf/ui/StackUtilsImpl.class] (Unsupported class version number [53.0] (maximum 52.0, Java 1.8))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided any details about your environment, but based on the error message (*"Unsupported class version number [53.0] (maximum 52.0, Java 1.8)"*) it looks like your code was compiled using JRE 9 (i.e. version 53.0).

There is an old Proguard feature request on this. See  [`#181 Java 9 major number 53 support`](https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/feature-requests/181/):

> Proguard does not support Java 9 class file format. The major version
> number for the class file in Java 9 is 53 and in Java 8 it was 52.
> Please enhance Proguard to support Java 9 class files.

The request was submitted on 12/21/16, and closed on 2018-03-29. Presumably you are using ProGuard 5.x (or earlier), right? If so, your solution is to use Proguard 6.0 or later. From the Proguard 6.0 release documentation:

> Added backporting and support for Java 9 code

However, if you are already using a version of Proguard > 5.x then update your question to provide full details of the compiled version of your code, and your versions of Proguard, Java and NetBeans.

Also see the old SO question [Error Proguard Unsupported class version number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22670059/2985643). Though not a duplicate of your question, it details a similar issue on earlier versions of Java and Proguard.